# How can I generate random variables with my own Probability Mass Function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, random

I have to generate a random variable that ranges from `20` to `30`,
with `0.1` interval, 
and the pmf of it is given by `1x101` matrix (for `x=20, 20.1, ... 29.9, 30`).

Now I have to make random variable with this given pmf,

But all I know about generating R.V is something related to gaussian, or uniformly distributed function.

So is there any way to implement generating random variables with arbitrary pmf?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick.

```
%// First I created some random data
N=1e6;
x=randn(1,N);x=(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x));
pmf=hist(x,101)./N;
%// It's a normal distribution but scaled to output to [0 1]

%// First, get the cdf
xh=cumsum(pmf);

%// Create the list of possible values of this random variable
Y=20:.1:30;

%// Create a uniformly distributed random variable between 0 and 1
R=rand()

%// Find where the cdf value is closest to R
[~,J]=min(abs(xh-R));

%// Find the resulting sample values
Y(J)

%// Just a little plot to make sure it's working
hold on
plot(Y,xh)
plot([20 30],[R R],[Y(J) Y(J)],[0 1])
hold off
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is multinomial sampling, see  http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrnd.html?refresh=true

If you just want one sample, you can (crudely) do something like

```
find( mnrnd(1,pmf))
```

where `pmf` is the vector of probabilities (`assert(sum(pmf)==1)`)

Note that there is nothing special of using 20:.1:30, you basically have 101 bins each with probability given by `pmf`